# Cryptic ClamAV results log file?

Tags: malware, anti-virus, malware-removal, logfiles, clamav

I installed `ClamAV` on LMDE4 and ran it using

```
sudo clamscan -ir ./ | grep FOUND >> /home/user/Desktop/clamscan_results.txt
```

The results file only contains the following:

```
Binary file /bin/ntfsfix matches
Binary file /bin/busybox matches
/etc/nsswitch.conf:hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

What does it mean? Also, when doing this

```
sudo clamscan / --recursive | tee clamscan.log
```

I can observe `Permission denied` being thrown for many files despite `sudo`. Why is that?

Comment: The result file looks like a result from `grep -r FOUND /` or similar. Maybe you redirected such command to the file earlier (by mistake?). Then it's possible `clamscan … | grep …` found nothing and you're only seeing the old content. Note `>>` does not truncate the file.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Yes, `grep` was used to produce the log file (see question)

Comment: My point is it looks like output from *sole* `grep -r FOUND /`. It absolutely doesn't look like output from `clamscan … | grep …`.

Comment: If you're not convinced yet then run `grep -r FOUND /bin/ /etc/nsswitch.conf` and see what you get. `clamscan` has nothing to do with this output.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Now I understand! And yes, you're right, doing that gives the same output. I ran `ClamAV` using this alias in my `.bashrc`: `alias clamscan='sudo clamscan -ir ./ | grep FOUND >> /home/user/Desktop/clamscan_results.txt`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you *are* doing wrong. But maybe you *have done* something wrong. `>>` does not truncate the file, so it's enough some erroneously invoked `grep` has written to the file once and you keep seeing it.

Comment: So the command is basically correct, but there might have been an error during execution? Okay, will try again and see if I can reproduce this...

Comment: ...this time, the logfile is empty. I find this strange, as on the system before I used to get many false positives with `ClamAV`. Is it to be expected that zero detection results in an empty file?